# Attrahite - A metal that conducts gravity

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology, physics, gravity

I have a metallic alloy called "Attrahite" in my world that conducts gravity the way that copper conducts electricity. Currently in the world, passing an electric charge through Attrahite "activates" it, conducting gravity, and leaving it without a charge "blocks" gravity from passing through.
Thus, you can create all kinds of toys like anti-gravity plates, "telekinesis" gloves, or an infinite sources of electricity (by spinning a turbine).

It's a fun idea, but I have a few problems with it (aside from the fact that it would blatantly violate the Second Law of Thermodynamics).
Can anyone think of a way that gravity could be manipulated by a material like this? Is it at all plausible, or should I find myself a new gimmick?

Comment: Are you looking at this as magic or as something to make magic?  What I really mean is will this be used to do weird stuff in war and other things, or just to make weapons?

Comment: What you describe sounds less like a copper wire conducting electricity and more like a semiconductor switching it.  Also, note that you can solve the whole perpetual-motion issue by making the act of switching it on or off require an amount of electrical power sufficient to make up for any potential energy changes that occur from blocking gravity.

Comment: What do you mean by "conducting" gravity? Gravity, either represented as flow of gravitons or curvature of space, goes through everything so "conducting" is pretty much what every material, as well as lack of material aka vaccum does. Blocking is what's unusual. Also, you can't really compare gravity to electricity in hard-science way, because there's no magnetic counterpart to gravity. Electrostatic and Magnetic interactions are unified to Electro-Magnetism, but there's no "Gravi-Magnetism", also, there's only one type of gravitational charge, since anti matter doesn't have anti-mass.

Comment: @Miech actually, there *is* [gravito-magnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism#Gravitomagnetic_fields_of_astronomical_objects).  And a negative mass would not have opposite gravity charge, as can be inferred that zero mass particles still work the normal way.

Comment: «can't really compare gravity to electricity in hard-science way,»  See also [Gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism), “a set of formal analogies between the equations for electromagnetism and relativistic gravitation; specifically: between Maxwell's field equations and an approximation, valid under certain conditions, to the Einstein field equations for general relativity. Gravitomagnetism is a widely used term referring specifically to the kinetic effects of gravity, in analogy to the magnetic effects of moving electric charge.”

Comment: I'm feeding it to my frog for a science project, a levitating and croaking frog! Oh wait di-gravi... what! how does that even works?

Comment: @JDługosz Never encountered that formalism. Lack of (L)orentz invariance is troubling as that breaks mass invariance, space-time interval and more. Actually, It seems it actually breaks General Relativity itself by breaking relativity principle. Lack of L invariance means that results of measurements do depend on speed. It seems that Gravimagnetism (and frame dragging) actually extrapolates GM outside of it's scope, so I wouldn't exactly call it reliable, and certainly not a theory (since it's self contradictory). If it's proven by experiment, it's a call to look for generalisation of GM.

Comment: @JDługosz Furthermore, cursory search suggests that those predicted effects (Gravimagnetism and frame dragging) have not actually been verified by experiment yet. If indeed so, then they are not actually part of hard science. Yet. That would mean that my claim IS correct. For now. Physics is an experimental science. It doesn't matter how nice and elegant your hypothesis is, all that matters is that it explains real phenomena and is verifiable by experiment. This remains to be seen, for now, what you linked is in limbo. But it's certainly good enough for hard sci-fi story.

Comment: [Gravity Probe B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_B) **has** actually **measured frame dragging** directly in a controlled apparatus. Case closed.

Comment: Attrahite is basically HG Wells' Cavorite with an extra wrinkle, Namely, gravity passes through while an electrical current flows through it. This probably won't upset the Second Law of Thermodynamics, but is a problem for the Conservation of Energy. It is normally a gravity insulator and conductor when electricity pass through it. This might work better the other way around, at least, that could conform to the Conservation of Energy.

Comment: The predictions of frame dragging, radiation, etc. come directly from GR, and is not “extrapolated beyond it's[sic] scope”.  If they were not bourne out with the measurements, there would be a **big** “back to the drawing board” movement.  The “approximation” in likening it to the far simpler Maxwell’s laws is a useful low-energy limit. But the secondary effects of moving gravitating objects is a real thing, no question.

Comment: Was that the only experiment so far? What about lack of Lorentz invariance? On other note, don't assume that every mathematical derivation of the model is automatically correct. Just like springs, models break if you stretch them too far.

Comment: « What about lack of Lorentz invariance? »   The “approximation” in likening it to the far simpler Maxwell’s laws is a useful low-energy limit. But the secondary effects of moving gravitating objects is a real thing, no question.

Comment: In a direct comparison to electrical conductors, anything with mass would be considered a charge carrier (like the electron in the wire).  So a gravitationally conducting material would be one that allowed the flow of mass, due to the gravitational potential.  So like a waterfall would be an example of air(?) conducting gravity, with water being the mass charge carrier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Make up some rules

It’s not remotely scientifically realistic. Why would that keep you from using it? Just declare that gravity on your world works like EM radiation and is transmitted by graviton particles. Most materials interact with gravitons by expressing a force of attraction, but attrahite does something else.

Here is one scenario consider. Lets say that gravitons are like neutrons. Neutrons will penetrate many objects to a decent distance, and even when they do not pass through without a collision, they are scattered. But some specific elements (Boron, Halfnium) absorb those neutrons instead. Attrahite could absorb gravitons in a certain way, completely removing gravitic energy and transferring it to some sort of atomic energy, much like the energy of neutrons absorbed is partially transfered to strong force bonds in the new nucleus.

Another thing to consider if you go with the above model, is that some energy that is absorbed can be re-released by certain processes. Certain energy gamma rays can be abosrbed in a crystal lattice. If that lattice is heated, the energy is re-released. This is the principle by which [thermoluminescent dosimiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoluminescent_dosimeter) work. Atttrahite could absorb gravitons, then be induced to release them by heating, exposure to sunlight, chemical reaction, or something.

There are of course infinite other scenarios dending on what you determine the gravitons to act like. Are they like electrons in that they have a 'gravitic charge' that attracts or repels them, and attrahite is the only other compound with a 'gravitic charge'? Is attrahite the only material that interacts with gravitons by repulsion? There are so many options.

Answer (score 0):

Such a universe would be very different from ours.  What you call *gravity* there, as you describe it, would not be like gravity in the real universe.

You’d need to ask the [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) geeks whether it is even *possible* to formulate a force that works this way.  It’s not like the electric force because you have like charges attract.  It may have one charge only, or maybe there’s just nothing with other charges around.

The carrier bosons interact with “other things” so they can be generated or stopped. You postulate interaction with electromagnetism, but that affects *everything* as matter is made of protons and electrons.

I worry that you would not have stable orbits.  Besides [the way (real) gravity points to the actual center rather than a time-delayed position](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/grav_speed.html), your world’s gravity would be altered by the composition of objects and things in the way.

Comment: just nothing with other charges around -  wouldn't work. The only reason it seems to work with static electricity is because the "neutral" object has equal amount of both, and opposite ones are attracted, end up nearer the charged object, their attraction is thus stronger than repel of same sign charges that ends up farther from each other.

Comment: @Mołot dipoles are not what I was getting at.  Given that **like charges attract** and everything has that same charge, it works similarly to gravity. This is unlike electric charge where likes repel.

Comment: Do you recall any force that would work that way irl? Because opposite charges repelling would cause an interesting effects. But I belive I never heard of it.

Comment: @Mołot the [interneucleon force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) comes to mind.  All baryons have the same “charge” and you can see that antimatter works the same, since the pion is the same if you reverse the matter/anti assignments.